# Help needed setting up RFC 868 (port 37) time service on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: networking, virtualbox, time

I have Ubuntu 12.04 running inside VirtualBox on Windows 7. I also have an older development platform which needs to set its internal clock by using the old time protocol. I'll admit that I'm by no means a sysadmin, (although this has experience has shown me the need to learn more), and since there seems to be nothing on the net on how to do this...

What I've done so far:

```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nfs-common nfs-kernel-server xinetd ;; nfs needed too
```

My edited /etc/xinetd.d/time:

```
# default: off
# description: An RFC 868 time server. This protocol provides a
# site-independent, machine readable date and time. The Time service sends back
# to the originating source the time in seconds since midnight on January first
# 1900.
# This is the tcp version.
service time
{
    disable        = no
    type           = INTERNAL
    id             = time-stream
    socket_type    = stream
    protocol       = tcp
    user           = root
    wait           = no
}                                                                               

# This is the udp version.
service time
{
    disable        = yes
    type           = INTERNAL
    id             = time-dgram
    socket_type    = dgram
    protocol       = udp
    user           = root
    wait           = yes
}
```

It needs tcp so I changed 'disable' to 'no'. Did this:

```
   sudo /etc/init.d/xinetd restart
```

The documentation said check the port with telnet:

```
   sudo telnet localhost 37
   Trying 127.0.0.1...
   Connected to localhost.
   Escape character is '^]'.
   ?gConnection closed by foreign host.
```

Having never used telnet, (don't laugh...), I don't even know what this means, so I believed that I might need to open up the firewall:

```
   sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 37 -j ACCEPT
   sudo iptables -L
   Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
   target     prot opt source               destination         
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:time
   ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

   Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
   target     prot opt source               destination         
   ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

   Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
   target     prot opt source               destination
```

Which is probably WRONG. The software I'm attempting to use says it can't set its time via the network so I hope that someone can help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `iptables`, the service is working as expected.

`telnet` connects to localhost at port 37, `xinetd` sends the 32-bit unsigned integer representing the time (that's the `?g` you see at the output) and closes the connection.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have to figure out why it can't see the network. Could it be a nfsd configuration foul up on my part?